# App icon doesn't match "recent apps" icon

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-mac, appicon

Working on Visual Studio for Mac.
I put new icon into the drawables and set the manifest appicon onto this resource. When I launch the app everything is correct in the menu, but the icon doesn't change in "recent apps" window.

I tried to delete every "default" icon on the project and replace it by mine icon, but still there is that green hexagon on recent apps menu. Hand deleted the app form the phone and builded my project again. Nothing helps. Only solution I found were working on Android Studio, but how to set the right icon on Visual Studio for Mac?

Comment: And how is this relevant to programming?

Comment: As far as i know icon is set in a programming IDE in code(manifest). Isn't it programming?

Comment: Have you tried the project on another machine? Icon is probably saved in cache and it's shown even though your app no longer has that icon